# Get value after changing input value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my script that after changing input value should send it to php file with Ajax.But it's sending the actual value from input field which is set via php.How can i set the new value to be given?

```
var idg;
var newg;

$('input.readonly').live("click",
    function() {
    $(this).attr('readonly', false);
    idgs=$(this).attr('id');
    newg=$(this).attr('value');

    $(this).change(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'new.php',
          data: "idgs="+ idgs +"&newg="+ newg,
          success: function(data) { $('.right').html(data); }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: can you point out the line where you are changing the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).change(function(){
 $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'new.php',
      data: "idgs="+ idgs +"&newg="+ $(this).val(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('.right').html(data);

      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var idg;
var newg;
$('input.readonly').live("click", function(){

    $(this).attr('readonly', false);

    $(this).change(function(){
        idgs=$(this).attr('id');
        newg=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'new.php',
            data: "idgs="+ idgs +"&newg="+ newg,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.right').html(data);
            }
        });

    })

});
```

This should do it, you where filling `idg` and `newg` with the default values, before they changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `val()` method like this:

```
newg=$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `newg` with `.val()` instead, and set it in the `change` handler to grab the updated value.

```
newg = $(this).val();
```

Also, you might find it more readable to pass an object to `data`, a la:

```
data: {
    'idgs': idgs,
    'newg': newg
},
```

Full code:

```
$('input.readonly').live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr('readonly', false);
    $(this).change(function () {
        var idgs = $(this).attr('id');
        var newg = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'new.php',
            data: {
                'idgs': idgs,
                'newg': newg
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.right').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```